# Print from text file to console using a selected method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, text, streamreader

So i can't seem to find anything about this online.
So i'm wanting to know how to print data from a text file to the console application through a method.

Here's an example,
This is the class Student, and the method I am wanting to use as a type of layout is DisplayInfo():

```
class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public Student(string SID, double SC)
    {
        ID = SID;
        Score = SC;
    }

    public void DisplayInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ID,": " + Score);
    }
}
```

Here is what i've got so far inside my PrintData void:

```
public void PrintData()
{
    using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
    {
        string readMeText = readtext.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Basically, again, I am wanting to print it in the format shown in DisplayInfo(), inside the PrintData() void.

Comment: You have mistake in `Console.WriteLine(ID,": " + Score);` it may be must be  `Console.WriteLine(ID+": " + Score);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you have text (demo.txt) file in this format :

> s1 140
>   s2 250
>   s3 400

Where `s1`,`s2`,`s3` are studeintID and `140`,`250`,`400` are their scores.

Now you need read lines from file while it is not the `End of Stream` split read line by whitespace and write to console. The following function is doing right that:

```
public void PrintData()
{
    using (var readtext = new StreamReader(@"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\demo.txt"))
    {
        while (!readtext.EndOfStream)
        {
            string currentLine = readtext.ReadLine();
            var args = currentLine.Split(' ');
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[0] + ":" + args[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid line");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Here is example how you can use object serialization/deserialization for this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            students.Add(new Student("s1", 140));
            students.Add(new Student("s2", 200));
            students.Add(new Student("s3", 250));
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
            if(!File.Exists(@"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\demo.txt"))
            {
                using (File.Create(@"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\demo.txt"))
                {

                }

            }
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\demo.txt"))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer,students);
            }
            PrintData();
        }
        [Serializable]
        public class Student
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public double Score { get; set; }

            public Student()
            {

            }
            public Student(string SID, double SC)
            {
                ID = SID;
                Score = SC;
            }
            public void DisplayInfo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ID+ ": " + Score);
            }
        }
        public static void PrintData()
        {
            using (var readtext = new StreamReader(@"c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\demo.txt"))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
                List<Student> readStudents = (List<Student>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readtext);
                foreach (var student in readStudents)
                {
                    student.DisplayInfo();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @William.K1 yes it's possible but for that you will have to Serialize Student  objects to text file when you will keep students to file and than Deserialize back when you want to read from file and write to console

Comment: not too sure what you mean. Whenever I try anything with DisplayInfo within PrintData, it just says that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @William.K1 I have updated my answer with example how you can do it

Comment: That's insane. Thank you :)